# Setting op table in SAS via proc tabulate

Tags: sas

I have some data about students and their dropout procent. I have information abaout which education they started on, in a city (some educations are found in more cities) and the year they started their education. I also have information about wheter there were a quotient the studetns had to meet to be able to start their education.

The quotient variable can consist of numeric values and character values (see the table)[image]

I want to make a table in SAS where I have the quotient and the dropout % like in the below picure: 
[image]

So for each education and for each city I have the years out as rows and in the cells I have the quota for that year and the dropout % for the year.

I can not do it in SAS. I have tried:

```
proc tabulate data= sammensat  missing;
var dropout;
class  education year city quota ;
Table   education* city,year *dropout    all/ rts=180;
run;
```

This gives me part of the output I want. But I want another row showing the quota for each combination of education and city for each year.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: including the quota, and dealing with the char values.

Including quota is easy, if it's numeric.

```
proc tabulate data= sammensat  missing;
 class  education year city; 
 var dropout quota;
 Table   education*city*(quota dropout),year    all/ rts=180;
run;
```

You might need to add in statistics to those if they're not both the same (and both N); probably *mean for both, not sure exactly what your data looks like.

To deal with the character problem, you need to create a format that has either special values for the quota, if they're just assigned values (this city-year-education combination has no quota by definition), or uses values that show there is no quota (missing, 0, etc.).

```
proc format;
  value quotaf
    -1='NO QUOTA'
    -9='PASSED AUDITON'
     0-high=[3.1]
  ;
quit;
```

Then use that to format `quota`, either in the dataset or with a `f=` option on quota in the proc tabulate.